# Sampling from a Potts model in Python

Tags: python, mcmc

I was wondering if anyone knew if there is some code available in python to generate MCMC samples from a generic **Potts model** with q-states to generate proteins from within a Multiple-Sequence Alignment. Hence from a dimensional point of view this is a *1D* object of length *N*, where each position can take *q* state, with *q=21*.

I was surprised not to find anything already available from within Python. I know the existence of very efficient libraries to do so, for example [here](https://github.com/ranganathanlab/bmDCA), but I need to sample within a training procedure of a model, hence I cannot continuously call this module as it is too inefficient. Also ideally I would like the sampler also to work for batches of models. The ideal pseudocode I am looking for would be:

```
def get_samples(fields, couplings, N_samples):
    calculation ....
    return samples
```

Would really appreciate any indications of such libraries!